# Does Uber API work with a local environment? Getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue on my https://localhost

Tags: uber-api

Im currently testing the Uber API, and I havent been able to get any     results yet, since my webapp is getting a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" issue:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 422.

I've set already the origin URI:
https://localhost

But the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error keeps coming.
I will try to recreate the app on the Uber side, but Its kind of odd that it doesn't work the way its intended.

Comment: Recreating the app didnt work. It seems they have some problems on their side, since deleting or creating new server tokens is also not working: 
Failed to delete token, please try again later  <--

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `http://localhost:{PORT NUMBER}` as the allowed origin URI in the Authorizations tab of your developer dashboard. You'll want to update that URI to whichever you end up using in production.

See the documentation for CORS: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api-reference

Comment: This solves only for the OAuth 2.0 process. Regular GET (without user scope) are still hitting CORS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your msg 7imon7ays, it works also without the port.

It turns out that I got messed up with the LatLng Objects.  The way I figured it out was, this:
Since "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price" is a GET I tested this url on a browser:

"https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.625732&start_longitude=-122.377807&end_latitude=37.785114&end_longitude=-122.406677&server_token=xxxxxxx"

(replace xxxxxx with your server_token)...

And it worked!, I was able to see the output as expected, so digging deeper, I added a console.log(uberParams)  <- to my uberParams, and it turns out that all of them but the key were undefined:

This is what I was using: (Wrong)

```
var uberParams = {
            start_latitude : origin.latitude,
            start_longitude : origin.longitude,
            end_latitude: destination.latitude,
            end_longitude: destination.longitude,
            server_token:"xxxxxxx"
        }
```

Where origin and destination are both google.maps.LatLng Objects.
So, for the API, I was incorrectly sending this:

```
        {
            start_latitude : undefined,
            start_longitude : undefined,
            end_latitude: undefined,
            end_longitude: undefined,
            server_token:"xxxxxxx"
        }
```

And the UBER Api, was returning THIS ERROR: ->  Access-Control-Allow-Origin

That caused the confusion, because the origin_uri wasn't the problem, as soon as I changed the params to this:

```
var uberParams = {
            start_latitude : origin.lat(),
            start_longitude : origin.lng(),
            end_latitude: destination.lat(),
            end_longitude: destination.lng(),
            server_token:"xxxxxxx"
        }
```

Everything worked as expected.
A Note to my Uber Friends:  "Great API, poor Error handling and descriptions..."

Answer (score 0):

On you dashboard, for example, if your redirection Url is http://localhost:8888/book/user/return

Then your origin Url should be http://localhost:8888 no slash at the end.